# upload base 64 encoded pdf to S3 nodejs/meteorjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, meteor, amazon-s3

I have a pdf buffer obtained from echosign that I have converted to base64 encoded data. I want to upload that pdf to S3. Do I need to use atob to convert it back to pdf? (when I do that using atob npm package) the pdf uploaded becomes password protected (broken).

How should I go for it? I am using request module. When I get the signed document, it fails to load I guess it hasn't been uploaded properly. How should I do it? I am using my following code.

```
  options =
    url: #mysignedurl
    method: 'PUT'
    headers:
      'content-type': 'application/pdf'
      'x-amz-acl': 'public-read'
      'content-length': pdf.length
    body: pdf #pdf is my buffer recieved from echosign
  rpp = Async.runSync((done) ->
    request(options, (Err, httpResponse, res) ->
      done(null, resp)
    )
  )
```